# Question about polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an infinite domain and $p(x), q(x) \in R[x]$ such that $q(x) \neq 0$. If for all but a finitely many $s \in R, q(s)|p(s)$, then is is true that $q(x)|p(x)$ in $R[x]$? This seems a little silly, but I cannot figure out why it should be true or false. What about the case where $q(x)$ is not a constant and $q(x)$ is monic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, let $q(x)=2$ (identically), and let $p(x)=x(x-1)$. Then $q(a)$
divides $p(a)$ for every integer $a$, but $q(x)$ does not divide $p(x)$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to close down this post? I feel silly.

Comment: @Rankeya: This is not a silly question, no need to feel bad! And we should leave this up in case anyone else comes along with the same question.

Comment: I was actually trying to show that if $R$ is an integrally closed domain, then so is $R[x]$, and at some point I came across a statement of this nature. Oh well.

Comment: Don't worry about it, everyone slips up sometimes, I more than most. There is a way of flagging a moderator, and moderators are all-powerful.

Comment: André is correct, if you really want to delete this question, a moderator (such as myself) will be able to do it. But I do encourage you to leave it up, there is nothing wrong with seeking to improve your understanding.

Comment: The answer leaves the question open for non-constant polynomials $q$.

Comment: Okay. Can I edit this question to one where $q(x)$ is non-constant? Perhaps even that has a straightforward counter-example.

Comment: Ahh, Gerry and I had the same thought at almost the same time.

Comment: More substantial editing will be needed.  Let $q(x)=2(x^2+1)$ and $p(x)=x(x-1)(x^2+1)$.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks.

Comment: Andre one more small edit. Sorry!

Comment: If $R$ is a field, then $q(s)|p(s)$ for all $s$ such that $q(s) \ne 0$, no matter what $p$ and $q$ are.

Comment: @Rankeya: For $\mathbb{Z}$, and close relatives, the *positive* assertion would be that $q(x)$ divides $cp(x)$ for some non-zero $c$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $q(x)$ is monic, we can divide $p(x)$ by $q(x)$ in $R[x]$: $$p(x) = q(x) f(x) + r(x)$$ where $f(x), r(x) \in R[x]$ and either $r(x)=0$ or $\deg r < \deg q$.  If $r(x)=0$, then $q(x)|p(x)$.  Otherwise, since $q(s)|p(s)$ for all but finitely many $s$, then $q(s)|r(s)$ for all but finitely many $s$.  In other words, $(q,r)$ satisfy the same hypotheses as the initial $(q,p)$, except now we have the extra condition that $\deg r < \deg q$. So to prove the original statement, we must show that $\deg r < \deg q$ cannot happen if $q(s)|r(s)$ for all but finitely many $s$.

In the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$, this is easy: If $\deg r < \deg q$ then $|r(s)|<|q(s)|$ for sufficiently large $|s|$, so that we cannot have $q(s)|r(s)$ for such $s$.

More generally, if $R$ is a subring of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ where $d<0$, then $R$ is an unbounded, discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$, so a similar argument works.

On the other hand, as in my comment, if $R$ is a field, then the original statement is false because any polynomials $p$ and $q$ satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: I think this is quite a satisfactory answer, considering my question stemmed from a problem I was stuck on in Algebraic Number Theory. It would, however, be an interesting question, if my domain $R$ did not have a natural order.

Comment: It's also true for the ring of integers of any number field, since any counterexample would yield a counterexample in $\mathbb{Z}$ by taking the product of all conjugates of $p$ and and all conjugates of $q$.  In fact, so far I can't think of any counterexamples other than fields; if $\deg r < \deg q$ and $q(s)|r(s)$ for most $s$, somehow it looks like the ring would have to have "a lot" of units so it's pretty close to being a field.